# WSO2 Entreprise integrator

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI 6.1.1, when I launch the server under WSO2 EI Tooling, the console shows the following errors.

```
PROBLEM : –
    ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:63)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
        ... 11 more
    [2017-11-29 21:35:05,351] [EI-Core] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:63)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:233)
        ... 11 more
    --------------------
    AMQConnectionFactory Error while creating connection
    org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:485)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:343)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore.newConnection(JmsStore.java:305)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore.getConsumer(JmsStore.java:189)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsConsumer.reconnect(JmsConsumer.java:245)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsConsumer.receive(JmsConsumer.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingService.fetch(SamplingService.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingService.execute(SamplingService.java:120)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some process is already using the port `7712` making it unusable to the EI application.

Changing the port configuration in your config files would let you get through the exception. I would suggest you to check what application is using the relevant port in your machine.

Reference Article - [link](http://amalkas.blogspot.com/2017/02/wso2-esb-communication-with-wso2-esb.html)